# Theoretically speaking, does the following algorithm make any claims on convergence for non-convex and noisy functions?

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, gradient-descent

I was looking at the Robbins-Monro Algorithm, supposedly one of the original algorithms used for stochastic optimization (i.e. Some argue that the Robbins-Monro Algorithm can be considered as the ancestor for the "famous" Stochastic Gradient Descent Algorithm heavily used in Machine Learning and Neural Networks ):

[image]

**My Question:** Although this is described as a root-finding algorithm and not as a minimization algorithm, nothing in the above statement contains any reference of "noisy functions" or "non-convex" functions: Thus, does the Robbins-Monro Algorithm allegedly promise to "converge in probability" (i.e. find the true roots) for measurements available from *any* function? Or am I completely misunderstanding this?

Thanks!

**Note:** I am also curious in knowing about how the development of the Robbins-Monro stochastic root finding algorithm ultimately lead to the well-known modern version of the Stochastic Gradient Descent algorithm.

**Reference:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the statement contains something "noisy" . You want to find a root of some function but can only evaluate on unbiased sample of its value. Hence, your evaluations contain noise.

Regarding convexity: To minimize a function, it's necessary to find a root of the derivative. If the function is convex, the corresponding root finding problem is monotone. Since the article does not impose any restrictions as monotonicity, it also applies to non-monotone probelems.

Comment: @ Dirk: thank you so much for your answer!